# The button in my code works one time only

Tags: javascript, html, css

I did the simple code below :

- HTML & CSS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> javaScript Console </title>
        <style>
            button { text-align:center;
                     width:200px;
                     height:30px;
                     font-size:17px;
                     font-family:courier new;
                     border:solid 2px black;
                     font-weight: bold;
                     background-color:lightblue; 
                     cursor:pointer;
                     border-radius: 20px;
                     transition: 0.5s; 
                    }

            button:hover {
                          transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
                          font-size:19px;
                          background-color: cyan;
                    }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body style="text-align:center">
        <fieldset>
        <legend style="text-align:center;margin-bottom: -20px"><h1 id="h1" style="text-align:center;">javaScript tests on console</h1></legend>
        <p style="color:green;"> Have fun coding !</p>
        <br/> 
        <div style="text-align: center;"><button id="btn" onClick="buttonHandler()" >Show time</button></div>
        <p id="time" style="color:blue;"></p>
        <p id="tick" style="color:red;"></p>
        <p></p>
    </fieldset>
        <script src="./test.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

- JavaScript:

```
console.log('Console is working fine !'); 

/**********************************************************************/
var x = 60;
function tick() {
    var date = new Date();
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = date;
    x--;
    document.getElementById('tick').innerHTML = `The time will be hidden after ${x} seconds`;

}

function clearAll(id) {
    window.clearInterval(id);
    document.getElementById('time').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('tick').style.display = "none";
}

function buttonHandler(e) {
    var id = window.setInterval(tick,1000);

    setTimeout(()=> clearAll(id),60000);

}

/**********************************************************************/
```

But the button 'Show time' works only the first time then if try to show the date again it doesn't work.
If i am not mistaken, i think that the problem is that the method setInterval() works only once, but i don't know how to fix that.

Can someone tell me how to fix this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you hide the element at the end of the timer in the `clearAll` function:

```
document.getElementById('time').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('tick').style.display = "none";
```

So you have to display them again when you click again.

Also if you click on the button multiple times, you'll run the function `tick` multiple times and it will decrement the timer faster.

I implemented a guard to prevent running the function multiple times and the timer is reset.

```js
console.log('Console is working fine !'); 

/**********************************************************************/
var x = 60;
var isRunning = false;
function tick() {
    var date = new Date();
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = date;
    x--;
    document.getElementById('tick').innerHTML = `The time will be hidden after ${x} seconds`;

}

function clearAll(id) {
    window.clearInterval(id);
    document.getElementById('time').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('tick').style.display = "none";
    isRunning = false;
}

function buttonHandler(e) {
    if (isRunning == false) { // To prevent multiple click to run multiple tick function
        isRunning = true;
        x = 60; // Reset timer
        document.getElementById('time').style.display = "block"; // Display again
        document.getElementById('tick').style.display = "block"; // Display again
        var id = window.setInterval(tick,1000);


        setTimeout(()=> clearAll(id),60000);
    }
}

/**********************************************************************/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> javaScript Console </title>
        <style>
            button { text-align:center;
                     width:200px;
                     height:30px;
                     font-size:17px;
                     font-family:courier new;
                     border:solid 2px black;
                     font-weight: bold;
                     background-color:lightblue; 
                     cursor:pointer;
                     border-radius: 20px;
                     transition: 0.5s; 
                    }

            button:hover {
                          transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
                          font-size:19px;
                          background-color: cyan;
                    }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body style="text-align:center">
        <fieldset>
        <legend style="text-align:center;margin-bottom: -20px"><h1 id="h1" style="text-align:center;">javaScript tests on console</h1></legend>
        <p style="color:green;"> Have fun coding !</p>
        <br/> 
        <div style="text-align: center;"><button id="btn" onClick="buttonHandler()" >Show time</button></div>
        <p id="time" style="color:blue;"></p>
        <p id="tick" style="color:red;"></p>
        <p></p>
    </fieldset>
        <script src="./test.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```